# Extracting Windows executable installers on Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, installer, extract

Is there a program or a script out there to extract the contents of a Windows installer under Mac Os X?

Under Windows there is the [Universal Extractor](http://legroom.net/software/uniextract), I am looking like something like that for Mac. I don't know if there is a universal solution to this problem or if I would need a extractor specific to the type of installer. In my case I am actually trying to get the installer from [Gog.com](http://www.gog.com/) to extract so I can use them with [Boxer](http://boxerapp.com/).

Answer (score 1):

Try **The Unarchiver**.
See http://unarchiver.c3.cx/formats

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't work.

Comment: From the link below: "Many kinds of .exe self-extracting formats are supported. However, if you find one that is not, please post an issue on the bug tracker." There's also support for MSI, NSIS and CAB archives.

Comment: I've had limited luck with 7-Zip. There's a command line version for OS X.

Answer (score 0):

If you have [macports](https://www.macports.org/install.php), do the following:

```
sudo port install p7zip
7z x self_extracting_nsis_archive_foo.exe
```

Answer (score 0):

@user3076105's answer works with [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/), too:

```
brew install p7zip
7z x some_windows_installer.exe
```

Make sure to put it in a new folder first so it doesn't spew files all over your ~/Downloads directory.

Another tip is that sometimes installers will contain additional installers and you may need to repeat the 7zip extraction command (`7z x foo.exe`) on some `.exe` files you find the first time you extract.